# Can I use onError attribute to trigger a HTML data-remodal-target?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website, and I recently  got Remodal for it.
Since the modals trigger using the data-remodal-target, when an error occurs, such as an image or stylesheet fails to load, I want to display a modal saying that the site is broken or not functioning. Thanks.

The usual use looks a little something like this:

```
    <a data-remodal-target="modal">Call the modal with data-remodal-id="modal"</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Make sure that the script that handles the error runs first.

```html
<script>
// Error handler function
function myFunction(){
    alert('Something went wrong');
}
</script>
<image src="" onerror="myFunction()"></image>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" onerror="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Thanks. I had put the script in a seperate file ;D and that must be why it didnt work